# hive-metastore is not able to start in the cloudera manager installation process

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, impala, metastore

We are installing `Cloudera CDH4` in `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`, In the installation step we are stuck at hive meta-store start. We have configured the `meta-store` with `MySQL` as recommended in download documentation.

Its giving us the following error:

```
/usr/lib/hive/conf$ sudo service hive-metastore status
 * Hive Metastore is dead and pid file exists
```

In the log file its showing the following error:

```
ERROR metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:main(4153)) - Metastore Thrift Server threw an exception...
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: No keytab specified
```

Following is out `hive-site.xml` file:

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
     <value>jdbc:mysql://my-local-system-ip:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
          <value>hive</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>my-password</value>
    </property>
    <property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoStartMechanism</name>
  <value>SchemaTable</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
  <value>file:///usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://<FQDN>:9083</value>
    </property>

<property>
  <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
  <description>Enable Hive's Table Lock Manager Service</description>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <description>Enable Hive's Table Lock Manager Service</description>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>KERBEROS</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>hive/_HOST@<my-domain-name></value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
  <value>10001</value>
  <description>TCP port number to listen on, default 10000</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
  <value>/etc/hive/conf/hive.keytab</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <description>Zookeeper quorum used by Hive's Table Lock Manager</description>
  <value>FQDN</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.zookeeper.client.port</name>
  <value>2181</value>
  <description>
  The port at which the clients will connect.
  </description>
</property>
   <property>
  <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.sasl.qop</name>
<value>auth</value>
<description>Sasl QOP value; one of 'auth', 'auth-int' and 'auth-conf'</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout</name>
<value>3600</value>
<description>MetaStore Client socket timeout in seconds</description>
</property>
```

Our main focus is to install `impala`. If we use default derby. Hive meta-store is working perfectly. But when we start `impala-shell`. It shows us Not Connected. What can we do rectify this ?

Can anybody help us out to this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're missing the following parameter:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file</name>
  <value>/etc/hive/conf/hive.keytab</value>
  <description>The path to the Kerberos Keytab file containing the metastore thrift server's service principal.</description>
</property>
```

I see you do have hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab, but it appears this is not enough.

Comment: Now m getting the following error `ERROR metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:main(4153)) - Metastore Thrift Server threw an exception...
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Kerberos principal should have 3 parts: hive`

Comment: Something is wrong with your hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal setting. It should have three parts in this format: username/fully.qualified.domain.name@YOUR-REALM.COM

so with what you have, "hive" should be the username for the kerberos principal. _HOST [I gather from here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_9_1.html) is a special thing that should sort itself out, but you need to make sure RDNS is working. The last bit should be your kerberos realm, not your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

replace "my-domain-name" in hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal property with your domain name. That is the third part which is missing in hive principal.